# sql defining a row by number of times / how it appears as other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm looking to recategorise some relatively simple information in the most efficient way possible:
Using a limited selection of sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #data
(id varchar(30)
,payent_type varchar(30)
,payment_date DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #data values ('001','single gift',DATEADD(MM,-12,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO #data values ('001','regular gift',DATEADD(MM,-39,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO #data values ('002','regular gift',DATEADD(MM,-06,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO #data values ('003','single gift',DATEADD(MM,-96,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO #data values ('003','regular gift',DATEADD(MM,-96,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO #data values ('003','single gift',DATEADD(MM,-1,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO #data values ('004','single gift',DATEADD(MM,-54,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO #data values ('005','regular gift',DATEADD(MM,-2,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO #data values ('005','regular gift',DATEADD(MM,-8,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO #data values ('006','single gift',DATEADD(MM,-12,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO #data values ('007','regular gift',DATEADD(MM,-2,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO #data values ('007','regular gift',DATEADD(MM,-6,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO #data values ('008','single gift',DATEADD(MM,-1,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO #data values ('009','single gift',DATEADD(MM,-80,GETDATE()))
INSERT INTO #data values ('010','single gift',DATEADD(MM,-54,GETDATE()))
```

And turning it into this:

```
ID   |   2005  |  2006  |  2007         |  2008  |  2009       |  2010
001  |   NULL  |  NULL  |  regular gift |  NULL  |  Both gifts |  NULL
```

Where basically if ID has both a single and a regular gift for a year then call it 'both gifts', if there is only a single gift then 'single gift' and if there is only a regular gift then 'regular gift'.

This data would then be used as part of another larger query.

I'm finding it easy enough to work out if an ID ever gave a single or regular (or both) gift, but I'm struggling to work it out on a year-by-year basis without creating a series of temporary tables which slows things down massively

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT** This is a very simplified version of the actual data I have - the real data has up to 200 rows per ID, and can contain multiple gifts per year of each type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this match what you need?

```
;with IDYearSummary as
(
    select
        id,
        MAX(CASE payment_type WHEN 'single gift' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as single,
        MAX(CASE payment_type WHEN 'regular gift' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as regular,
        DATEPART(year,payment_date) as year
    from
        #data
    group by
        id,DATEPART(year,payment_date)
), MixGifts as
(
    select
        id,
        CASE
            WHEN single=1 and regular=1 THEN 'both'
            WHEN single=1 THEN 'single'
            WHEN regular=1 THEN 'regular'
        END as gifts,
        year
    from
        IDYearSummary
)
select
    id,
    [2002],
    [2003],
    [2004],
    [2005],
    [2006],
    [2007],
    [2008],
    [2009],
    [2010]
from
    MixGifts
        pivot (MAX(gifts) FOR year in ([2002],[2003],[2004],[2005],[2006],[2007],[2008],[2009],[2010])) as pvt


drop table #data
```

Comment: Fantastic - works the quickest for my actual table so accepted as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This query works using the test data you have provided.

```
Select * 
From
(
Select  ID, 
        'both gift' as 'PaymentType',
        Datepart(Year, payment_date) as 'Years'
From #data
Group by Id, Datepart(Year, payment_date)
Having Count(Distinct(Payment_Type)) > 1

    Union All

Select  ID, 
        Max(Payment_Type),
        Datepart(Year, payment_date)
From #data
Group by Id, Datepart(Year, payment_date)
Having Count(Distinct(Payment_Type)) = 1

    Union All

Select  ID, 
        Null,
        Datepart(Year, payment_date)
From #data
Group by Id, Datepart(Year, payment_date)
Having Count(Distinct(Payment_Type)) = 0
)q

Pivot  (max(PaymentType) for Years in ([2002],[2003],[2004],[2005],[2006],[2007],[2008],[2009],[2010])
)p
```

Comment: Unfortunately (as I've now included in the question), I can have many rows per ID (up to around 200) and there can in theory be an endless number of rows of each gift type - thanks

Comment: Is this gift type only going to be either `single gift` or `regular gift`

Comment: Yes, the gift type is always fixed to be either single or regular, it's just that for each ID there can be multiple references of each for each year

Comment: Thanks Barry, this does work fine, just takes quite a long time, but good to learn about pivoting a union! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH Data AS
    ( SELECT id, YEAR(payment_date) AS payment_year,
        CASE
            WHEN MAX(payent_type)<> MIN(payent_type)
            THEN 'Both gifts'
            ELSE MAX(payent_type)
        END AS payent_type
    FROM #data
    GROUP BY YEAR(payment_date),
        id
    )
select id,[2002],[2003],[2004],[2005],[2006],[2007],[2008],[2009],[2010]
from data
Pivot  (max(payent_type) for 
      payment_year in ([2002],[2003],[2004],[2005],[2006],[2007],[2008],[2009],[2010])) pvt
```

Comment: Thanks for this - how does the MAX(payment_type) <> MIN(payment_type) when payment_type is not a numeric? Had no idea you could do a MAX of a VARCHAR!! :)

Comment: Max and Min on strings means the alphabetically first and last.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to explain the solution - works perfectly just a bit slower on my table than accepted answer.